# How can I filter records in nested queries and then select other columns in the same table from the filtered results?

Tags: sql-server, join, reporting-services, parameters, subquery

First, I want to filter and only select OBJECTIDS in two nested queries (based off of user entered parameters, @Borough and @WOEntity) and then join columns (Type and Priority) from the same table back to the most refined set of records. The purpose of this is to improve the performance of stored procedures that sit behind an SSRS report.

I'm getting these error messages:

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 13
> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'SELECT'
>
> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 36
> Incorrect syntax near ')'

My query looks like this so far:

```
declare @Borough int
declare @WOEntityINT int = NULL --0, 1, 3, 4, 11, 10, NULL

set @Borough = 1
set @WOEntityINT = 1


SELECT 
    B.OBJECTID, WO.Type, WO.Priority
FROM
    CFAdmin.WorkOrder_EVW as WO
WHERE 
    B.OBJECTID = WO.OBJECTID

(
SELECT A.ObjectID
FROM
    (SELECT
         ObjectID,
         CASE 
            WHEN WOEntity = 0 THEN 0 -- In-House
            WHEN WOEntity IN (1, 2) THEN 1 -- Contract
            WHEN WOEntity IN (3, 4) THEN 3 -- Utility 
            WHEN WOEntity IN (5, 6) THEN 4 -- Permitted
            WHEN WOEntity IS NULL THEN 10 -- No Entity
            ELSE 11 --11 = Other
         END AS WOEntityINT                                         
     FROM 
         CFAdmin.WorkOrder_EVW
     WHERE
         (Status NOT IN (1, 2)) AND
         (Borough IN (@Borough))) AS A
 WHERE 
     (@WOEntityINT IS NULL OR (WOEntityINT = @WOEntityINT)) --field WOEntityINT is a derived field 
 ) AS B
```

Comment: When you start chopping out code when do you stop getting that message?

Comment: you cannot have FROM and WHERE for select query that has B.column_name's in it. As its a named query and has everything it needs encapsulated in.. (code) as B. If your trying to do a join back to WO again. You will have to do it after 'as B' via a left or inner with the criteria you have placed in your 'as B' From where clause.

Answer (score 1):

Your query must match with pattern: `SELECT FROM WHERE`. I mean, you can reorder clauses:

```
SELECT B.OBJECTID, WO.Type, WO.Priority
FROM CFAdmin.WorkOrder_EVW as WO
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT A.ObjectID
  FROM
    (
    SELECT
        ObjectID,
            CASE 
                WHEN WOEntity = 0 THEN 0 -- In-House
                WHEN WOEntity IN (1,2) THEN 1 -- Contract
                WHEN WOEntity IN (3,4) THEN 3 -- Utility 
                WHEN WOEntity IN (5,6) THEN 4 -- Permitted
                WHEN WOEntity IS NULL THEN 10 -- No Entity
                ELSE 11 --11 = Other
            END AS WOEntityINT                                          

        FROM CFAdmin.WorkOrder_EVW
        WHERE
            (Status not in (1,2)) AND
            (Borough IN (@Borough)) 

     ) AS A

   WHERE (@WOEntityINT IS NULL OR (WOEntityINT = @WOEntityINT)) --field 
   WOEntityINT is a derived field 
 ) AS B
 on B.OBJECTID = WO.OBJECTID
```

Remember you can write CTE to improve readability:

```
WITH a AS 
( 
       SELECT objectid, 
              CASE 
                     WHEN woentity = 0 THEN 0      -- In-House 
                     WHEN woentity IN (1,2) THEN 1 -- Contract 
                     WHEN woentity IN (3,4) THEN 3 -- Utility 
                     WHEN woentity IN (5,6) THEN 4 -- Permitted 
                     WHEN woentity IS NULL THEN 10 -- No Entity 
                     ELSE 11                       --11 = Other 
              END AS woentityint 
       FROM   cfadmin.workorder_evw 
       WHERE  ( 
                     status NOT IN (1,2)) 
       AND    ( 
                     borough IN (@Borough)) )
, b AS 
( 
       SELECT a.objectid 
       FROM   a 
       WHERE  ( 
                     @WOEntityINT IS NULL 
              OR     ( 
                            woentityint = @WOEntityINT)) --field 
              woentityint IS a derived field 
) 
SELECT     b.objectid, 
           wo.type, 
           wo.priority 
FROM       cfadmin.workorder_evw AS wo 
INNER JOIN b 
ON         b.objectid = wo.objectid
```

Disclaimer: This is just a suggestion to start to debug and isolate your problem. I guess, after this changes, you will found new issues. Please, don't ask for new issues in this post.